# Correct use of react states and routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am new to react and I haven't cleared all things in my mind yet.

I am currently working on a project where I need to build a react app with a landing page, a sign up/in page, an ask-a-question page and a answer-question page. Something like a stack overflow clone.

To my knowledge so far I get that I have two choices. 1) use react-router and have a function rendering what I want for each page or 2) have a state like showPage and with some if/else if render the page I want.

What is the correct way to do what I want? And in general when should I use react-router and when just state.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're going to have a lot of code complexity if you try and have a single route that swaps out views. Especially with something like a login or register page, it's good to isolate that logic away from other code.

Comment: As @VtoCorleone said, you would be doing the same thing using state which react-router does for you. The only difference is that react-router uses history push state api under the hood and swaps the view depending upon the route which is what almost all the SPA(single page apps) do. I think you should definitely use react-router here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll always use routing if you have multiple pages to render. As you said you have 3 pages currently you'll need to work on.

1. Landing page
2. Sing in/ register
3. FAQ
   What you'll want to do is wrap everything inside your app.js in `Router` and have say a `pages` folder that'll have all the pages you want to render.

> In React, routers help create and navigate between the different URLs
> that make up your web application. They allow your user to move
> between the components of your app while preserving user state, and
> can provide unique URLs for these components to make them more
> shareable. With routers, you can improve your app’s user experience by
> simplifying site navigation.

Read more [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-routing-in-react-apps-with-react-router)

You need to separate all this because when your project grows you'll thank yourself for creating specific file for specific workload. It'll be easier to manage. And when you're working on large scale projects you'd want to create layouts and have even bigger distributions.

```
layouts
|__admin_layout.js
|__user_layout.js
```

here admin layout will handle all routes specific to admin and user layout will handle all routes specific to users.

Routing helps you manage your pages much better